# android How to send listview item to another activity

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I am trying to send row item from list view to another activity but maybe I do something wrong.

I made one app for food.
And I want when the user click to "First Activity" the list item from this listview to be send to "Second Activity" and when the user click to "Add to cart" the listview item go to Cart.class

But when I click to "Add to cart" the Activity is send me tо Cart.class but there have nothing.

In cart.xml I have listvew.

Sorry for my bad english

Thanks in advance.

First Activity.

```
public class UnderCal extends Activity {


String classes[] = {"Grilled chicken","Asiago","Spicy"};


int[] meal = new int[]{
        R.drawable.grilledchicken,
        R.drawable.asiago,
        R.drawable.spicy


};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    setContentView(R.layout.under_menu);



   final List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

        hm.put("food", Integer.toString(meal[i]));

        hm.put("txt", "" + classes[i]);

        aList.add(hm);

    }


    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = {"food","arrow","txt"};

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.food,R.id.arrow,R.id.txt};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.list_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    final ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0xffffffff));
    listView.setDividerHeight(1);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {


            if (position == 0)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UnderCal.this,GrilledChicken.class);

               // intent.putExtra("get", aList.get(position));


              String result = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
              intent.putExtra("get",result);
              startActivity(intent);

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation3, R.anim.animation4);




    }


    }
    });

}
```

Second Activity.

```
public class GrilledChicken extends Activity {


Button butadd;


//HashMap<String, String> hm;

String  list;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    setContentView(R.layout.grilled_chicken);


    //hash
   // hm =(HashMap<String, String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("get");


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    list = extras.getString("get");     

    butadd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.butadd);


    butadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Intent intent = new Intent(GrilledChicken.this,Cart.class);
            // intent.putExtra("hm",hm);

            intent.putExtra("list",list);


            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);

            }


    });
```

Cart.class

```
public class Cart extends Activity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    setContentView(R.layout.cart);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String pos = extras.getInt("list");

     }
 }
```

Comment: but in cart activity you are not getting data using Bundle.

Comment: did you got list in second activity???

Comment: No,I don't have listview in Second activity.Second activity is like a bridge between first activity and Cart.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code in your `Cart.class`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String   list_data = extras.getString("list");
```

Now `list_data` contains the data.

There is another way through which you can do the task also.

Create a separate Global Class

**Global.class**

```
public class Globalclass {
    public static String list_data;

}
```

And then in your `FirstActivity` replace the following

```
intent.putExtra("get",result);
```

with

```
Globalclass.list_data=result;
```

Now you can access the `list_data`anywhere like the following

```
String data=Globalclass.list_data;
```

Answer (score 2):

For get item from your listview you have to write following code.

```
String item = food.get(position).toString();
```

Write this on your Itemclick method

Answer (score 1):

Try this once I hope this will help you.

First of all do this in `YourFirstActivity`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourSecondActivity.class);
            YourModel yourModel = (YourModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("yourModel", yourModel);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

At another `Activity` do this.

```
YourModel yourModel= (YourModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("yourModel");
```

From `yourModel` `object` you will get all the data of your `ListView` selected item of `YourFirstActivity` to `YourSecondActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Send ListView Item:-

```
 ArrayList<String>checked11 = new ArrayList<String>();
 SparseBooleanArray checked = listView1.getCheckedItemPositions();
 final ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
     int position = checked.keyAt(i);
     if (checked.get(i))
         selectedItems.add(checked11.get(position));
 }

 String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

  for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
       outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
  }
```

use Bunddle :

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    OtherActivity.class);
 bundle.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);
 intent.putExtra("screen2", "sub");
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESPONSE, selected);
 startActivity(intent);
```