# How to get a string variable from another activity to databaseaccess.class for using in a database query?

Tags: android, sqlite, bundle

Hi i have an activity that listing city names in a listview. i want to pass pressed item's text to databaseacces.class by bundle and using it as a variable in database selection query. But i cant use bundle because of databaseaccess.class isnt an activity. How can i do this?
code block in main activity:

```
if (position>=0){


        bundle.putString("cityname",String.valueOf(position+1));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and my databaseaccess.class code block:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle data=intent.getExtras();
     city=data.getString("cityname");

     city=(String) intent.getExtras().get("city");

}
    public List<String> getQuotes() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bank_table WHERE City = "+city,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(1) + " " + cursor.getString(2) + "\nAdres: " + cursor.getString(3) + " " + cursor.getString(4) + " " + cursor.getString(5) + "\nTel: " + cursor.getString(6) + "\nFax: " + cursor.getString(7));

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass it in bundle? can't you just set it in your databaseAccess? you can also create a listener so when item in list is clicked, your other class knows and make w\e it wants.

Comment: Are you calling getQuotes() from your activity? If so, just pass the city name to it.

Comment: Thank you very much i solved my problem with this way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17964126/3809268